# Best way of creating multiple pipelines in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am actually implementing the continuous integration pipeline of the company I am working for with the help of Jenkins.

What I have done so far is a bit basic:

Create as many jobs as stages in my pipelines and then **Build a pipeline view** with the jobs I created before. So far so good but just for the test pipeline I have created.
I mean, this pipeline runs over a project.  If I want to apply the same 'pipeline actions' against other project, I have to create again all jobs that are within the pipeline > create the Build a pipeline view and I will have another pipeline.

I am trying to extrapolate this into the Jenkins a code concept so that my pipeline will be formed by groovy code and the only thing left to do would be change the name of the project.

What do you guys think about my approach on building Jenkins pipelines?

Cheers,
Sebastian

Comment: Take a look at Job DSL plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin

Comment: Hi. Yes, I am actually creating the regular pipeline, plenty of jobs, with a jenkins file, which is a kind of dsl description using Groovy.

Comment: It is an interesting approach. But I recon you do not gain much out of pipelines methodology. The idea of pipeline is to have Production to Deployment description. And the pipeline as you use them are just steps. Other then that, is sound reasonable approach, as long as you do not add those pipeline files into your repository.